# apache beam 2.7.0 craches in utf-8 decoding french characters

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, apache-beam

I am trying to write a csv from a bucket of google cloud platform into datastore, containing **french characters/accents** but I have an error message regarding decoding.

After trying encoding and decoding from "**latin-1**" to "**utf-8**" without success (using *unicode, unicodedata and codecs*) I tried to change things manually...

The Os I am using, has the "**ascii**" encoding by default and I manually changed in "*Anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/site.py*" into utf-8.

```
def setencoding():
    """Set the string encoding used by the Unicode implementation.  The
    default is 'ascii', but if you're willing to experiment, you can
    change this."""
    encoding = "utf-8" # Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

I've tried locally with a test file, by printing and then writing a string with accents into a file, and it worked!

```
string='naïve café'
test_decode=codecs.utf_8_decode(string, "strict", True)[0]
print(test_decode)

with  open('./test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(test_decode)
```

But no luck with apache_beam...

Then I've tried to manually change "*/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py*" and put "**ignore**" instead of "**strict**" into codecs.utf_8_decode

```
def decode(input, errors='ignore'):
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
```

but I've realized that apache_beam do not use this file or at least does not take it into account any changes

Any ideas how to deal with it?

Please find below the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "etablissementsFiness.py", line 146, in <module>
    dataflow(run_locally)
  File "etablissementsFiness.py", line 140, in dataflow
    | 'Write entities into Datastore' >> WriteToDatastore(PROJECT)
  File "C:\Users\Georges\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipel
ine.py", line 414, in __exit__
    self.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "C:\Users\Georges\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runne
rs\dataflow\dataflow_runner.py", line 1148, in wait_until_finish
    (self.state, getattr(self._runner, 'last_error_msg', None)), self)
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow
pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py",
line 642, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", lin
e 156, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.nativ
e_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.nativ
e_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.nativ
e_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
    with self.spec.source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 48, in dataflow_worker.nativ
e_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
    for value in reader:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 2
01, in read_records
    yield self._coder.decode(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", li
ne 307, in decode
    return value.decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 190: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write a CustomCoder class and "ignore" any errors while decoding:

```
from apache_beam.coders.coders import Coder

class CustomCoder(Coder):
    """A custom coder used for reading and writing strings as UTF-8."""

    def encode(self, value):
        return value.encode("utf-8", "replace")

    def decode(self, value):
        return value.decode("utf-8", "ignore")

    def is_deterministic(self):
        return True
```

Then, read and write the files using the `coder=CustomCoder()`:

```
lines = p | "Read" >> ReadFromText("files/path/*.txt", coder=CustomCoder())

# More processing code here...

output | WriteToText("output/file/path", file_name_suffix=".txt", coder=CustomCoder())
```

Comment: I was trying to read a utf-16-le decoded file, but was running into the following issue: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 1256: truncated data. I was able to solve my issue by also defining the delimiter with ReadFromText(...,delimiter="\r\n".encode("utf-16-le")).

Answer (score -1):

This error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte"
means, that you CSV file still contains some wrong bytes not recognized by the decoder as UTF characters.

The easiest solution for this, is to [convert](https://www.charset.org/utf8-to-latin-converter) and validate csv input file to not contain UTF8 errors before submitting for Datastore. [Simple online UTF8 validation can check it](https://onlineutf8tools.com/validate-utf8).

If you need to convert latin-1 to UTF8 in python, you can do it like that:

```
string.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
```