# Read UTF-16 csv with Apache Beam/ Dataflow in Python

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The issue that is regarding the reading of csv files with UTF-16 formatting. The installed Apache Beam is version 2.7.0 with Python2.7. On the github of Apache Beam it is being said that the function `ReadAllFromText(PTransform)` cannot handle UTF-8 [1].
Is there a alternative to read UTF-16 csv files with Apache Beam?

[1]https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py

Comment: Try to build your own CustomCoder class and set decode/encode to "utf-16" -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644674/4832821