# UnicodeEncodeError for csv paring on apache beam in python

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, python-unicode

I am working on parsing a CSV file in apache beam python. However when there's some unicode characters in the CSV file like "ş" it failed to parse with error

`RuntimeError: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u015f' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128) [while running 'Parse CSV']`

I tried use `unicodecsv` package and assign coder when open the file with `beam.io.ReadFromText` but doesn't help. However if I escape the character 'ş' to \u015F in the CSV and it will work. Is there any fix or proper way to read a UTF-8 encode file in apache beam (python) ?

```
import apache_beam as beam
import unicodecsv as csv

pipeline = beam.Pipeline('DirectRunner')

csvparser = (pipeline
  | 'Read CSV' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://blahfoo/test.csv', coder=coders.StrUtf8Coder())
  | 'Parse CSV' >> beam.Map(lambda line: next(csv.reader([line], quotechar='"', encoding='utf-8')))
)

pipeline.run()
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is UTF-8? According to the docs `ReadFromText` supports UTF-8, but not UTF-16 or UTF-32: https://github.com/apache/beam/blame/378d9079cdc8cf8582c0ba2f03ab6a393c878dcb/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py#L485

Comment: Try to write your own Coder class -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644674/4832821

Comment: Hi, prove to create a custom coder and use chardet/cchardet to detect the encoding line by line